# A way to query Neo4j by property sorted by highest or lowest values

Tags: java, neo4j

In Neo4j if I want to find nodes with the highest or lowest property values I can use the Cypher keywords Order By and Limit. I'd like to accomplish the same using the embedded API. I know Lucene can support this but can't see how to do this with Neo's API.

```
public TopFieldDocs search(Query query,  int n, Sort sort)
```

https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/index/ReadableIndex.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into this and the answer is Yes, this can be done. The second argument in `IndexHits<T> query( String key, Object queryOrQueryObject )` can be a parseable (by `org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser`) String, a `org.apache.lucene.search.Query`, or a `org.neo4j.index.lucene.QueryContext`

Here's a code snippet that allows for requiring an "EntityType" property to have a specific value, requires a numeric property to be non-blank, and returns the top n hits sorted by the numeric property.

```
...
List<TopNValue> values = new ArrayList<>();
QueryContext queryContext = getQueryContext(entityType, property, propertyType, n, true);
try (IndexHits<Node> indexHits = nodeIndex.query(property, queryContext))
{
  for (Node node : indexHits)
  {
    values.add(node);
  }
}
...

private static QueryContext getQueryContext(String entityType, String property, String type, int n, boolean reversed)
{
  NumericRangeQuery propertyQuery;
  int fieldType;
  switch (type)
  {
    case GraphTypes.LONG:
      propertyQuery = NumericRangeQuery.newLongRange(property, Long.MIN_VALUE, Long.MAX_VALUE, true, true);
      fieldType = SortField.LONG;
      break;
    case GraphTypes.DOUBLE:
      propertyQuery = NumericRangeQuery.newDoubleRange(property, Double.MIN_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE, true, true);
      fieldType = SortField.DOUBLE;
      break;
    case GraphTypes.FLOAT:
      propertyQuery = NumericRangeQuery.newFloatRange(property, Float.MIN_VALUE, Float.MAX_VALUE, true, true);
      fieldType = SortField.FLOAT;
      break;
    case GraphTypes.INT:
      propertyQuery = NumericRangeQuery.newIntRange(property, Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE, true, true);
      fieldType = SortField.INT;
      break;
    default:
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot create NumericRangeQuery for type: " + type);
  }
  Query query;
  if (entityType == null)
  {
    query = propertyQuery;
  }
  else
  {
    TermQuery entityTypeQuery = new TermQuery(new Term("EntityType", entityType));
    BooleanQuery booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();
    booleanQuery.add(entityTypeQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
    booleanQuery.add(propertyQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
    query = booleanQuery;
  }
  Sort sorting = new Sort(new SortField(property, fieldType, reversed));
  return new QueryContext(query).sort(sorting).top(n);
}
```